# How to upgrade a jailbroken 4th gen iPod touch to 5.1 or higher?

Tags: ipod-touch, upgrade, jailbreak, 4g

I was wondering how I could upgrade my jailbroken iPod touch 4g (4.1) to 5.1 or higher?

I found the following instructions by cksum on the forum:

> You will require iTunes. Connect the device, then right click on it in
>   the iTunes side bar. Select "Back Up." Allow it to runs its course.
>   Close iTunes.
>
> Then put the device into DFU mode:
>
> 1) Power off the device.
>   2) Disconnect it.
>   3) Hold the power button for 2 secs.
>   4) Without letting go of the power button, press and hold the home button for 10 secs.
>   5) Let go of the power button but not the
>   home button for another 10 secs.
>
> Reconnect the device and launch iTunes. It will detect your iPad and
>   inform you it is in recovery mode. From there, it will check for the
>   newest available update (5.1), download it and install it. When that
>   completes, simply restore your device from the backup you made
>   earlier.

But I was just wondering if after this I would have to jailbreak my iPod again.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, if you upgrade, you will have to jailbreak your device again.**

Updating your device will restore your iPod Touch to its default settings, removing any and all jailbreak apps and cracks. But I've been told that an iOS 6 jailbreak is available so you should be able to do it all over again.

Comment: thank you! :-) so I would basically have to follow the instructions above and then re-jailbreak!

Comment: It's a tethered Jailbreak for A4 devices on iOS 6.

Answer (score -2):

Actually go into cydia and download  osupgrade and it will let you upgrade to any ios

Comment: Could you expand your answer? Please provide a link too

Comment: Upgrade any device to any OS seems too good to be true. Perhaps someone can edit in what this means in practice or better document what the osupgrade package is capable of doing?